# Convert between Timezones

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to convert between different timezones using momentjs but I can't get it right

This is the code I am using:

```
let Santiago = moment.tz("2006-01-03 08:00", "America/Santiago");

let london     = santiago.clone().tz("Europe/London");

console.log("Santiago: ", santiago.format());

console.log("London: ", london.format());
```

Output:

Santiago: 2006-01-03T08:00:00-03:00

London: 2006-01-03T11:00:00Z

My local timezone is set to Santiago (UTC-04:00).

I am expecting to see 5 hours difference but I can only see 3.

any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: I think it's because is set daylight saving time (DST) in Santiago.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones